# Text inside input not spacing

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, responsive-design

[image: On chrome mobile]

[image: On desktop]

```
input#submit {
position: relative;
background: transparent;
bordeR: none;
font-family: raleway;
text-transform: uppercase;
border: 1px solid #1ba39c;
margin-left: auto;
font-size: 13px;
display: block;
color: #1ba39c;
letter-spacing: 1px;
top: -5px;
left: -1px;
padding: 7px;
padding-top: 8px;
}
```

As you can see on chrome mobile the text inside of input with the value post comment gets moved upwards whereas on chrome desktop it perfectly centered. What must be the issue?

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is? Can you elaborate a bit more please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear what you're asking, but see if the following CSS change achieves what you are looking for:

```
textarea#comment {
    background: transparent;
    height: 28px;
}
```

I think this is @ line 1663 of http://tenfizz.com/wp-content/themes/tenfizz/style.css

Good luck!

Comment: Look at post comment button with green border.. the text inside the button is moved up on mobile and whereas on desktop it's centered